# Highcharts Column Graph with background color?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to make a column graph in Highcharts and it's not working out too hot. I'm essentially trying to give the column a background color that the data point can overlay. I want the effect of stacking without actually stacking if that makes sense. Any thoughts on what I can do?
Essentially I want it to look like a progress bar... there should be a distinct coloring between the top of the bar and the top of the graph itself. I've already tried stacking: percentage, but to no avail. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you paint the desired effect (feels like the best way to understand it)? You want the bar to continue all the way to the top, when it really doesn't do that?

Comment: Try to use [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands) - you can render plotband under the bar/column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three options that come to mind:

1) To achieve the 'effect' of stacking, actually stack it: use a dummy series with a color set to the background color that you want, and set with values to fill the gap from the actual data.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Zf8C7/5/

**[[edit for questions**

The order of the series does not matter for this to work, and neither does the legendIndex.

What does matter, if you are using multiple series, is the `stack` property for each series - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.stack

Each group will need its own stack, and the dummy series and real series within each group need to be assigned to the same stack.

In addition, you need to have one overall max value.

Updated example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4d9tm6b8/4/

(keep in mind, there are much smoother methods to process and build your data - this is a quick and dirty example whose purpose is to show how to properly use the `stack` property to do what you need)

**]]**

*2) plotBands, as mentioned above*

*3) using the alternateGridColor property and set your data to skip an x axis 
value between each point.*

*Reference:*

*- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.alternateGridColor*

Comment: Wow - this is awesome. Thanks! I want to use Example #1, but it seems like there will never be a maximum, unless I can somehow calculate the max of the data coming in, and then subtract. I'll try that out.

Comment: Easy enough to auto calculate. Personally I would probably use max data value + 10% or something to give a little padding, but depends on use.  Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4d9tm6b8/

Comment: That would work, except I'm working with multiple arrays! I could calculate the yAxis's max value, but then I won't have that number until the data is populated into Highcharts, and I can't render it all twice, right?

Comment: Why do you need to send it to the chart first? Define all of your data arrays first, do whatever calculations you need to do, and then run the chart code. Doesn't matter if you have one array or one hundred.

Comment: Only thing left is since I have many series that I'm working with, would I just alternate? data, ndata, data, ndata? And that way the legendindex is just alernating between 0 and 1, and then just use index to define the order?

Comment: Oh! I actually saw that you can name stacks. Got it! Thanks!!! You're a highcharts wizard.